# Mapping a boundary value problem: Jacobian in NDSolve and refining mesh close to a point

Tags: differential-equations, mesh, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I would like to solve the (oversimplified!) BVP

$u''(x)-u(x)=0,\qquad x\in[0,\infty)$

with the condition $u(0)=1$. I thought to remap this into the BVP problem

$D[J^{-1}(\xi)u(\xi)]-J(\xi)u(\xi)=0, \qquad \xi\in[0,1)$

with boundary condition(s)

$u(0)=1,\qquad u(1-\varepsilon)=0\quad \mathrm{or} \quad u'(1-\varepsilon)=0\,.$

The coordinate transformations and the Jacobian $J$ are

$\xi=\frac{x}{1+x},\quad x=\frac{\xi}{1-\xi}\rightarrow J(\xi)=\frac{dx}{d\xi}\,.$

The Mathematica (v10.3) code is

```
J[ξ_] = D[ξ/(1 - ξ), ξ] // Simplify;
f = NDSolveValue[{
 D[u'[ξ]/J[ξ], ξ] - J[ξ] u[ξ] == 0, 
 u[0] == 1, 
 u'[1 - 1*^-3] == 0
 }, 
 u, {ξ, 0, 1 - 1*^-3}]
```

function plots and relative error

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{#, f[#/(1 + #)]} & /@ Subdivide[0, 10, 20]],
 Plot[Exp[-x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[{#, (f[#/(1 + #)] - Exp[-#])/f[#/(1 + #)]} & /@ 
   Subdivide[0, 10, 20], PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}
 ]
```

`NDSolveValue::berr` provides an error on convergence (tolerance).

There is a better way to solve this problem. Maybe providing a jacobian to NDSolveValue? Adapting the mesh to the boundary $x=1$?

Thanks for the suggestions,

F

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution.

```
J[\[Xi]_] = D[\[Xi]/(1 - \[Xi]), \[Xi]] // Simplify

interval = DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}],
   MeshRefinementFunction -> 
    Function[{v, a}, a > 1/(1/(-1 + Mean[v])^2)]
   ];

\[Alpha] = 1;
f1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u'[\[Xi]]/J[\[Xi]], \[Xi]] - 
     J[\[Xi]] \[Alpha]^2 u[\[Xi]] == 0, u[0] == 1}, 
  u, \[Xi] \[Element] interval, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 20]
Show[
 ListPlot[{#, f1[#/(1 + #)]} & /@ Subdivide[0, 20, 40]],
 Plot[Exp[-\[Alpha] x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[{#, 
     Abs[(f1[#/(1 + #)] - Exp[-\[Alpha] #])/(1 + 
         Exp[-\[Alpha] #])]} & /@ Subdivide[0, 20, 40], 
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2}}
 ]
ListPlot[{#, 
    Log10@Abs[(f1[#/(1 + #)] - Exp[-\[Alpha] #])/(1 + 
         Exp[-\[Alpha] #])]} & /@ Subdivide[0, 20, 20], 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

it consists in discretize the interval with increasingly finer elements for the point at infinity (in this case according to the Jacobian), and remove the boundary conditions at infinity.